# How to find a conformal mapping from the upper half plane onto the first?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Let be $D$ the open unitary disk. Find a holomorphic transformation (bijective) from $D$ to $A=D$ \ $ [0,1)$.

What I've done is a Möbius transformation from $D$ to the upper half plane ( $\mathbb{U}$ ), a Möbius transformation from the first quadrant to $D^{+}$={$ |z|<1, \text{Im}(z)>0$}. If I apply $z^2$ to this set I get $A$ right? But how to send  $\mathbb{U}$ to the first quadrant?
Thought about $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$, but this isn't holomorphic.

I will thank any suggestions.

Comment: $\sqrt z$ is holomorphic on simply connected domain which do not contain $0$. The first quadrant is such a domain.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos is it holomorphic when I considerer a branch like the logarithm? Im learnig complex analysis and I dont get at all how it works the branchs.

Comment: Yes. To be more precise, I should have said that on simply connected domains without $0$ *there exists a branch* of $\sqrt z$ which is holomorphic. For instance, if you slash the complex plane so it doesn't exclude the negative real axis or $0$, then the main branch of $\sqrt z$ is holomorphic. The first quadrant is just a subset of this slashed plane, so the main branch is also holomorphic on the first quadrant.

Comment: Key point, the original D is the open disc, so removing the half open real segment [0,1) does not result in any surprises; the resulting set still does not contain 1, and is simply connected.   Negating rotates the picture by 180 degrees, so $\sqrt {-z}$ is well defined on $A$